# How to use mongoose-validators options

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Mongoose validators has the option to skip null values and empty strings for example, but how do I use them?

Answer (score 0):

As documented: [mongoose-validators](https://github.com/niklasvh/mongoose-validators)

> Each validator type can be passed an optional options object as the
>   first argument. The following common options can be defined:
>
> skipNull - Skip validation if the value is null or undefined, default:
>   false
>
> skipEmpty - Skip validation if the value is and empty string
>   (""), null or undefined, default: false
>
> message - Override the default
>   error message returned when validation fails.

You can use it like below example where I use `skipEmpty` option:

```
var opts={skipEmpty:true};
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {type: String, validate: validators.isEmail(opts)}
});
```